# Notification is not handled when user clicks on the application icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm not (yet :)) an expert in iOS development.

I use Cordova/PhoneGap to convert my Javascript app into native app.
I use [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) in order to handle notifications.

The whole works well when user clicks on the notification alert:  handled by the application through the `onNotificationAPN` callback.

However, when user clicks on the app icon directly (with the badge incremented), the notification is not handled => `onNotificationAPN` callback not fired.

I'm not expert in Objective-C and iOS environment but I'm suspecting this snippet code from PushPlugin to not achieve my requirement:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"active");

    //zero badge
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    if (self.launchNotification) {
        PushPlugin *pushHandler = [self getCommandInstance:@"PushPlugin"];

        pushHandler.notificationMessage = self.launchNotification;
        self.launchNotification = nil;
        [pushHandler performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(notificationReceived) withObject:pushHandler waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

How to handle notification when user clicks on the app's icon rather than the alert ?
**Especially, why isn't it a default in this plugin? Does it make sense I ignore?**
Indeed, it would lead to many unprocessed notifications as users usually clicks on the app icon rather than the alert.

Comment: I don't know phonegap or pushplugin but in iOS native application If your app in back ground you can handle the push notification only by tapping the alert.

Comment: @jailani But what is the real reason regarding this behavior? Why not handling the notification? When I'm using Whatsapp for instance, and clicking on the app's icon, I expect the app to show me new conversations alerts, what it does. I don't want to "pull" for new data each time the user's clicks on the app even if there were no current notifications.

Comment: I am sorry another one callback will get called if the application receives notification even if the app is not in the background

Comment: @jailani Does it mean that in traditional iOS native apps, when user's clicks on the app icon, there is ALWAYS a process that PULLS for new data ? Of course, this questions concerns the case when the app is not fully closed, but in background initially.

Comment: before I click the app icon that delegate method will called on that method we can receive the information pushed by APNS and we can update the data source inside the application.

Comment: I understand, so it means that to achieve my use case, I have to "patch" the plugin code to retrieve notifications.

Comment: @Mik378 This UIApplicationDelegate callback that you've showed, will be called each time the user opens the app. So i don't know phonegap, but i think that in your case if there is a notification in "pending" and You open the app from the icon, the if statement should be true.